# What makes a factor valid in a factor pricing model of assets?

Tags: finance, asset-pricing

This question is related to another question [here](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/107/examples-of-factors-in-the-icapm). The question linked to asks for examples of factors commonly used in ICAPM models (intertemporal capital asset pricing model). What I want to know here is this: what is underlying principle that makes a factor a valid factor in factor models such as the CAPM, ICAPM, or APT?

Answer (score 1):

This is a partial answer (see section 5.1, p. 79 of Cochrane's book, "Asset Pricing"). Suppose you wanted to treat the size of the firm as a factor. Stocks of smaller firms typically have higher average returns. You could then form a "large" holding company comprised of smaller firms. The new, large company would then have returns like a smaller company but would in fact be large and "the managers could enjoy the difference."

> What ruins this promising idea? The "large" holding company will still *behave* like a portfolio of small stocks---it will have their high betas. Thus, only if asset returns depend on *how you behave*, not *who you are*---on betas rather than characteristics---can a market equilibrium survive such simple repackaging schemes.

(How would I formalize this concept?)

EDIT: Also, in Financial Asset Pricing Theory by Munk (chapter 10, p.371) it says

> It is worth emphasizing that the general theoretical results of the consumption-based asset pricing framework are not challenged by factor models. ... Factor models do not invalidate the consumption-based asset pricing framework but are special cases that may be easier to apply and test. *Therefore factors should generally help explain typical indiviudals' marginal utilities of consumption.*

(Emphasis added) This helps to understand the role of factors in the ICAPM.